# dependency property - member not recognised or not accessible

Tags: user-controls, windows-8, microsoft-metro, dependency-properties

I have created a `UserControl` and inside it defined a dependency property `Label`. When I refer it in a control I get the error the `The member "Label" is not recognised or is not accessible`. What I don't understand is that it works perfect on windows phone but after porting the app to windows 8 it gives this error. Is there something different to be done for windows 8 user controls? Please help.

Comment: can you add your xaml to this question?

Comment: Will need to see a code snippet to help. Dependency properties done correctly for Windows Store apps should work just fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to http://leventoz.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/moving-a-windows-phone-app-to-windows-8-a-case-study-part-2/

I just closed my .xaml file and the error went away. Bug with Visual Studio it says. But its not confirmed. Still it works for me.

Comment: Thank you! Similar problem here: worked in WPF, but not in Win8. I've lost a day and a half on this.

Comment: Ran into the same issue.  Closing and opening the .xaml was not enough, but restarting VS did it.